# Trying to make columns in text file from python

Tags: python

So far I have this. I opened the data file, I was able to make a list from the data and print the data I needed from the list in 2 columns correctly. It shows up in python just fine. But when I try to write it to a txt file, it all shows up on 1 line. Not sure what to do so it's into 2 columns in the new text file.

```
# open file
data = open("BigCoCompanyData.dat", "r")
data.readline()

# skip header and print number of employees
n = eval(data.readline())
print(n)


# read in employee information
longest = 0
# save phone list in text file
phoneFile = open("PhoneList.txt", "w")


for i in range(n):
    lineI = data.readline().split(",")
    nameLength = len(lineI[1])+len(lineI[2])
    if nameLength > longest:
       longest = nameLength
       longest = longest + 5

    print((lineI[2].title()+", "+lineI[1].title()).ljust(longest) + ("("+lineI[-2][0:3]+")"+lineI[-2][3:6]+"-"+lineI[-2][6:10]).rjust(14))


    phoneFile.write((lineI[2].title()+", "+lineI[1].title()).ljust(longest) + ("("+lineI[-2][0:3]+")"+lineI[-2][3:6]+"-"+lineI[-2][6:10]).rjust(14))


data.close()

# close the file
phoneFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`phoneFile.write(...)`simply writes the line you give it. Every time you give a line it appends it to the previous lines, unless you end your lines with `\n`.

```
phoneFile.write((lineI[2].title()+", "+lineI[1].title()).ljust(longest) + 
                ("("+lineI[-2][0:3]+")"+lineI[-2][3:6]+"-"+lineI[-2][6:10]).rjust(14)+'\n')
```